# Translating string into object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm constructing what needs to be a name of var on the fly using

```
var myNameToConstruct = 'prefix_' + t; // where t is a value passed as string from a function
```

Using this name I need to initiate a method of an object earlier defined as

```
var prefix_someName = $("#ele").getObjInstance(); // where getObjInstance is a method used by this particular object.
```

**prefix_someName** from my second line of code is an object in itself but the name I'm constructing is a string so even though it looks the same, it is not the same thing (what I gather from this code blowing up)

Is there a way to turn **prefix_someName**(string) into **prefix_someName**(object) on the go so that its recognized properly and the method can be called on it or do I have to rewrite code on a deeper level to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects are defined globally:

```
window[myNameToConstruct].methodToCall();
```

Comment: it is, and this works for me. Thanks. Is the limitation of this approach such that it would not work on local vars?

Comment: it would work, but that case you wouldn't be looking for your objects on the `window` object but in your local scoped object store. e.g: `var myObjectStore = { objectA: {}, objectB: {}};` you would reference objectA by: `var objectName = 'objectA', myObject = myObjectStore[objectName];`